# Display Alert dialog box in just of progress dialog completed android

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog, progressdialog, dialog

Hello friends i want to display alert dialog box in just of to the complete progress dialog box. progress complete upto 100 i want to ask/inform some information through  alert dialog box.i am well in both but i dont know how to integrate both so please help me quickly .. thanks in advance.
my code is following

```
                   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            no = 1;
            int a = lv.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "item " + a + " selected",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            System.out.println("progress start");
            progressDoalog.setMax(100);
            progressDoalog.setMessage("Connecting Please Wait....");
            progressDoalog
                    .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDoalog.show();
            progressDoalog.setProgress(0);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        // Here you should write your time consuming task...
                        while (progressDoalog.getProgress() <= progressDoalog
                                .getMax()) {

                            Thread.sleep(100);

                            handle.post(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {
                                    progressDoalog.incrementProgressBy(no);
                                }

                            });

                            System.out.println("before if");
                            if (progressDoalog.getProgress() == progressDoalog
                                    .getMax()) {

                                System.out.println("u r in if 100");
                                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                                System.out.println("dismiss");
                                //
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        context);

                                    alertDialogBuilder

                                        .setMessage("Password to Network")
                                        .setMessage(randomMessage)
                                        .setTitle("Password")
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Copy",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                                            }
                                          })
                                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                    alertDialog.show();
                                //
                                System.out.println("alert over");

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }).start();


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AsyncTask for this

```
    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
    /** do your initialization here like setting up porgress bar or some other 

variable it's up to you*/
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //do your work here 
                        //update progress bar 
                      publishProgress(total_progress);
            return flag;  //return true or false 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                     //set progress here
                     progressbar.setProgress(values[0])
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                  //deal with you alertdialog here
            if(result)
                     {
                      //do something with our alert dialog
                     }
                     else
                     {
                      //do something with your alert dialoge
                     }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the progress by passing the percentage value via handler to asycn task. Once it is completed show the alert dialog in postExecute().

Comment: please understand above through code ??? now i check if progress reac to 100 i try to display alert but it not display through follwing :                          if (progressDoalog.getProgress() ==         progressDoalog.getMax()) { my alert code }